# Looping through a multidimensional array error

Tags: c#

Im making a sudoku game. The Multidimensional array is called `array`. I basically flattening the array and search for dublicates. I cannot seem to turn this unefficient piece of code:

```cs
if(true)
            return
            findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, 0, 0))
            && findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, 0, 3))
            && findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, 0, 6))
            && findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, 3, 0))
            && findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, 3, 3))
            && findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, 3, 6))
            && findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, 6, 0))
            && findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, 6, 3))
            && findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, 6, 6));
}
return true;
```

into this

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 3)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j += 3)
    {
        if (findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, i, j))) return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Basically, the `flattenArray` method takes in a multidimensional array and 2 coordinates from which it flattens down a 3*3 piece of the array. For whatever reason it just returns false all the time.

I dont think its because of `findDoublicates` and `flattenArray` since they work perfectly in my other cases. In the upper example everything works fine but in the second example something goes wrong and i cant notice what it is.

Am i missing something obvious?

#### Answer

```cs
if(true)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 3)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j += 3)
        {
            if (!findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, i, j))) return false;  
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

forgot to invert the return of `findDoublicates`

Comment: So is this java or c#? Please don't tag irrelevant languages.

Comment: yeah i am jumping between java and c# and it didnt work in either. There isnt something very java or c# specific (besides couple of different method names) about this question so i just added them to it.

Comment: Side note: `if (true)` is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that you got your condition wrong in the second piece of code.

In the first snippet, you return `true` if all the `findDoublicates()` return `true`, and `false` on the first `findDoublicates()` that's `false`.

In the second snippet, you return `false` as soon as you find a `findDoublicates()` that is `true`.

Try this:

```
if(true)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 3)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j += 3)
        {
            if (!findDoublicates(flattenArray(array, i, j))) return false;  
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

Also, you might want to rename it `findDuplicates()`...

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't, but in the spirit of trying to answer the question without changing too many things I left everything else in place.

Comment: yes. I get that its not really usefull to keep it this way but if i try to shorten it more than it has to be im going to be confused. Thx @vmallet

Answer (score 0):

The first piece of code return true if every check are true, and false as soon as one of the check is false.

The second piece of code return true if every check are false, and false as soon as one of the check is true